# Create a sum of 1000, 2000, etc. from set of numers

Tags: algorithm

Ok, so here's the problem:

I need to find any number of intem groups from 50-100 item set that add up to 1000, 2000, ..., 10000.

Input: list of integers

Integer can be on one list only.

Any ideas on algorithm?

Comment: homework problems should be said so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Googling for "Knapsack problem" should get you quite a few hits (though they're not likely to be very encouraging -- this is quite a well known NP-complete problem).

Edit: if you want to get technical, what you're describing seems to really be the subset sum problem -- which is a special case of the knapsack problem. Of course, that's assuming I'm understanding your description correctly, which I'll admit may be open to some question.

You might find Algorithm 3.94 in [The Handbook of Applied Cryptography](http://www.cacr.math.uwaterloo.ca/hac/about/chap3.pdf) helpful.

Comment: It's not really this problem - in my case this is not optimalization - no need to get maximum number of results.

Comment: Getting *a* result is just a special-case of getting *the best* result. You're still in NP-complete land, unfortunately.

Comment: That's the answer, still O(n2^(n/2)) is sad but the best I can get.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% on what you are asking, but I've used backtracking searches for something like this before.  This is a brute force algorithm that is the slowest possible solution, but it will work.  The wiki article on [Backtracking Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking_search) may help you.  Basically, you can use a recursive algorithm to examine every possible combination.

Answer (score 1):

This is the knapsack problem. Are there any constraints on the integers you can choose from? Are they divisible? Are they all less than some given value? There may be ways to solve the problem in polynomial time given such constraints - Google will provide you with answers.

Comment: Knapsack problem has two parameters - weight and value. I have only weight. Constarints are that they are in range 1 - 10000, nothing more.

Comment: All integers can have a value of 1 in context of the algorithm, they can have value equal to their weight, or some other variant - it's just a matter of transforming your problem to fit the algorithm.